# Minimal polynomial of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

$A$ is a square matrix with a minimal polynomial of degree $k$.

> If $g(x)$ is a polynomial and $g(A)$ is invertible, then there exists a polynomial $h(x)$ of degree smaller than $k$ such that $(g(A))^{-1} = h(A)$.

Any hints on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main motivation behind the proof is the following trick:  If $S$ is an invertible matrix then the characteristic polynomial $\chi_S(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i t^i$ has $\chi_S(S) = 0$ by Cayley-Hamilton. Because $a_0 = \det(S) \neq 0$ it then follows by rearranging that
$$
 S \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{a_0}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_{i+1} S^i\right) = I
$$
$S^{-1} = -\frac{1}{a_0}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_{i+1} S^i$.

We generalize this trick: If $S$ is an invertible matrix and $P(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i t^i$ a non-zero polynomial with $P(S) = 0$, then there exists some polynomial $Q(t) = \sum_{j=0}^m b_j t^j$ of degree $m < n$ with $S^{-1} = Q(S)$. To see this let $0 \leq l \leq n$ be the smallest index with $a_l \neq 0$. Then
$$
0
= P(S)
= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i S^i
= \sum_{i=l}^n a_i S^i
= S^l \sum_{i=0}^{n-l} a_{i+l} S^i.
$$
Because $S$ is invertible the same goes for $S^l$, so it follows that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-l} a_{i+l} S^i = 0$ with $a_l \neq 0$. (One could also skip this previous step by assuming w.l.og. that the constant term of $P$ is non-zero.) Rearranging then gives
$$
0
= \sum_{i=0}^{n-l} a_{i+l} S^i
= a_l I + S \sum_{i=0}^{n-l-1} a_{i+1+1} S^i
\implies
S \sum_{i=0}^{n-l-1} a_{i+l+1} S^i
= - a_l I
$$
and thus $S^{-1} = -\frac{1}{a_l} \sum_{i=0}^{n-l-1} a_{i+l+1} S^i$.

Now let $m(t) = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i t^i$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ and let $g = \sum_{j=0}^n b_j t^j$. Notice that
$$
 m(g(A))
= g(m(A))
= g(0)
= b_0 I.
$$
So for the polynomial $P(t) = m(t) - b_0$ we have $P(g(A)) = 0$. If $P \neq 0$ then we are finished by our previous work because $\deg(P) \leq \deg(m)$.

If we had $P = 0$ then $m(t) = b_0$. Because $0 = m(A) = b_0 I$ this is only possible if $b_0 = 0$. Then $m(t) = b_0 = 0$, but the minimal polynomial $m$ must be non-zero!

Answer (score 1):

If $\def\Mn{\operatorname{Mat}_n[K]}K[A]\subseteq\Mn$ denotes the set of polynomials in$~A$ (with coefficients in the ground field$~K$), the question is whether any $B\in K[A]$ that is invertible in $\Mn$ has its inverse in $K[A]$.

Now the hypothesis that $B=P[A]$ is invertible implies that the polynomial $P$ is relatively prime with the minimal polynomial$~\mu_A$ of $A$. For if $D$ were a non-constant common divisor of $P$ and $\mu_A$, one would have on one hand $\dim(\ker(D[A]))>0$ (because $\ker(D[A])$ contains the image of $(\mu_A/D)[A]$ which is nonzero since $\deg(\mu_A/D)<\deg(\mu_A)$) and on the other hand $\ker(D[A])\subseteq\ker(P[A])$ (because $D$ divides $P$), which together contradicts the hypothesis that $P[A]$ is invertible.

But then there exist Bézout coefficients $S,T\in K[X]$ such that $SP+T\mu_A=1$. Applying the ring homomorphism $K[X]\to K[A]$ of evaluation at $X=A$ gives $\mathbf I=S[A]\circ P[A]+T[A]\circ\mu_A[A]$; since $\mu_A[A]=0$ by definition, one has $S[A]P[A]=\mathbf I$, so the inverse of $P[A]$ is $S[A]$, and it lies in $K[A]$.